# Failed to install gems via Bundler when pushing to Heroku on completed rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app using Heroku but whenever I run `git push heroku main` I keep getting the error

> Failed to install gems via Bundler.

Any help is appreciated

gem file

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.2"

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.3.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.3", ">= 7.0.3.1"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"




# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false


# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
  
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end

group :production do
  gem "pg"
end
```

> ---

```
 git push heroku main
Enumerating objects: 662, done.
Counting objects: 100% (662/662), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (628/628), done.
Writing objects: 100% (662/662), 80.33 KiB | 6.18 MiB/s, done.
Total 662 (delta 376), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.3.10
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-3.1.2
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.3.10
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        Your bundle only supports platforms ["arm64-darwin-21"] but your local platform
remote:        is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with
remote:        `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.
remote:        Bundler Output: Your bundle only supports platforms ["arm64-darwin-21"] but your local platform
remote:        is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with
remote:        `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to arcane-island-23619.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/arcane-island-23619.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try running `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` and committing the changes and then re-deploying?

Comment: that did the trick. What did that bit of code do?

Comment: https://bundler.io/v2.3/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS it's a constraint that says `bundle install` works on the platforms listed there.